sent mails appear in the list of drafts
does anybody have the same conspicuity?
Our finished and sent mails appear in the list of drafts and without the name of the sender.
Why? And how do we change this?
Regards,
Regina

We use CiviMail with CiviCRM 5.74.4 in WordPress 6.5.5.

not heard of it. do they Mailings actually have the same ID - if so is it possible that your displays of Mailings have been overwritten at some time in past so the filters have been modified - had to look up 'conspicuity'. have never seen it in use.

'conspicuity' was suggested by Google Translator ;-)

I ran into this with a client and traced it to some bad data in the mailings table. The completed mailings that show up in the draft page are those with a NULL value in the scheduled_id column.
I suspect there was a bug in an earlier version that caused that column to not be set properly when the mailing was scheduled. The unscheduled status filter on the mailing browse page uses that column to determine the status.
You can fix it with this query (replace "ID" with the actual ID of a contact you want to associate as the scheduler).
UPDATE `civicrm_mailing` 
SET scheduled_id = ID
WHERE scheduled_id IS NULL 
AND status = 'Complete'


Wow @lcdservices, thank you so much. This was the solution we needed.
Now everything works fine!

At https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/mailing/browse/scheduled?reset=1&scheduled=true there should be an exposed filter to determine what Mailings are going to show at each screen.
You can also see this in the url, since the scheduled one shows as
scheduled=true
while the Draft shows as
scheduled=false
These are the two screens from Dmaster
DRAFT

SENT


perhaps you can add screenshots and paths to your Question to help clarify the problem

Thank you fpr your help, @petednz!
I get an error message when I click on the demo link:
"Access denied - You are not authorized to access this page."
I didn't use screenshots as we have a german version, but maybe it's helpful though:
scheduled: https://stiftungaktivebuergerschaft-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/regina_sommerfeld_aktive-buergerschaft_de/EQCs4Dy1_gxGuLTO-XNedOQBlkGLiVFDwEwE_rHgtUmuTQ?e=sRSOmd
drafts: https://stiftungaktivebuergerschaft-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/regina_sommerfeld_aktive-buergerschaft_de/EeBzPprUBrNFs6OjTxEHmzgBFnxQ4wU3Ud7_eWOIGRdrVQ?e=WMfMMz

Sorry, I don't know how to insert images correctly ...

The images are fine and appear as they should / show on dmaster. Are the mailing IDs definitely the same for drafts and sent ones?

There is info at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/. It says "Just login with..., Username: demo, Password: demo"

or is someone making the Draft, then someone else is coming along and clicking 'copy' and then sending the copied version?

I compared all message IDs of drafts and sent mails and they are all identical.
And yes, we often use the procedure that one person writes the draft and another person is sending the mail (without "copy").
